# AVPlayer freeze screen on iOS 15, and then all system avplayer got freeze

Tags: ios, avplayer, ios15, avplayerviewcontroller

I do video editing program mainly synthetic, at the result page, when call `AVPlayerViewController` to preview the video.Sometimes after the method `viewWillAppear`, about 9 seconds later, I got follow error

```
[default] AudioSessionCopyProperty_Priv posting message to kill mediaserverd (3705)
[avas] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:114   AudioSessionGetProperty ('rcid') failed with error: 'what'
[avas] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:138   AudioSessionGetProperty ('rcid') failed with error: 'what',
the
```

and then, or system avplayers (not only in my app), will change its status to error, and can not play again.
Does anyone know what happend?